# Nginx reverse proxy. 1 external ip, 2 local servers

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, server, http-proxy

I have a problem I hope some can help me with.

I have an domain name pointing to a webserver (Pine64). The server is running some php.

Now I want to connect another physical webserver to the same domain but as a subdomain.

Both servers are running Debian with nginx, php and forced ssl.

So basically I need the following:

Https: // mydomain.name -> Pine64 server port 443 (ssl)
Https: // srv2.mydomain.name -> second local server post 443 (ssl)

Is it possible?

All examples I have found so far is for virtual domains on the same server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need a separate domain config ( considering future maintain) like this,
create a config file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/srv2.mydomain.name` with a content similar as below,

```
server {

  listen 80; # or 443 ssl related settings
  server_name srv2.mydomain.name; # note this part
  location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000$request_uri; # forward request to the server running on this ip:port
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
  # any other conf part
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked :-) Now I just have to figure out how to make file upload from iOS to next cloud working....giving me error 413 :-/

Comment: @DrDice Then post in SO if it needs (y)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible via nginx. Add two domain and just pass it through the proxy 
[you can find more details in here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)

Comment: I can't really see from that link how it can handle subdomain